# How to derive table value from an update in a second table (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to MYSQL and having a tough time with triggers. I'm working with PHPmyAdmin and using InnoDB as a storage engine.

My database is meant to structure a professional sports league. 
I have tables for teams and for divisions, and I want to set up the table so that a division's record can be calculated from the records of teams in that division. Here's my SQL for creating the team table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `cs340_neffj`.`teams2` ( `teamID` VARCHAR(3) NOT 
    NULL ,`teamName` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `teamWins` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
    `teamLoss` INT(3) NOT NULL , `divID` INT(1) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And here is for the divisions table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `cs340_neffj`.`divisions2` ( `divID` INT(1) NOT NULL , 
    `divName` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `divLeader` VARCHAR(20) NULL , 
    `divWins` INT(3) NOT NULL , `divLoss` INT(3) NOT NULL , `leagueID` INT
    (1) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

So what I would like to do is, each time a row in 'teams2' is updated, sum all the wins and losses of each team in a particular division and insert it into the divWins and divLoss columns of 'divisions2'. In 'teams2', divID is a foreign key referencing 'divisions2'. Here is my attempt at a trigger.

```
   INSERT INTO divisions2 (divWins)
   SELECT SUM(teamWins)
   FROM teams2
   WHERE teams2.divID = divisions2.divID
```

I get this error when I try to update 'teams2': "#1054, unknown column 'divisions2.divID' in 'where clause'.

So why can't the database find this column? Is it because there is no value for divID?

Comment: You have miss the `divisions2` in from clause...

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to SQL. Not really sure what you mean.

Comment: BTW, I think you should use [`View`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) instead of create middle table

Answer (score 0):

Just assume the record already exists in table `division2`

You should use `update` instead of `insert`

```
UPDATE divisions2 
SET divWins = SUM(teams2.teamWins)
FROM teams2
INNER JOIN division2 ON teams2.divID = divisions2.divID
```

`update` command will update the `division2` table
details of `inner join` you can refer to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp), which in short is select all data which match with the criteria

As my comment stated, I think these kind of data should use view instead of trigger.

For view:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT division2.`divID`, sum(teams2.`teamWins`) as teamWins
FROM teams2
INNER JOIN division2 on teams2.divID = divisions2.divID
```

So every time you select the view, it will calculate the `teamWins` on the same time.